# iPhone app run on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, resolution

I have uploaded an app developed for iPhone 5S, this week I uploaded an update where I simply changed some texts, no programming. And I reject it, the reason is to be compatible with iPad, meaning that if you the low to iPad screens should not be cut off (2X option). They are different resolutions, do not know how to make them compatible.

I have replied saying it is an app exclusively for iPhone and precisely I'm developing with many more features to iPad.

I have come to answer that yet, should look good on iPad.

The iPhone 5S resolution is 640 x 1136, and the iPad is 768 x 1024, regardless of the retina or new models of iPhone 6, 6 plus, ie more square.

As I can adapt it without creating a new storyboard exclusive ipad?

The weird thing about all this is that I will accept and update a simple throw me back.

Thank you

Comment: Did you change your app to be universal? If you're building just for iPhone, you're not responsible it to be compatible to iPad.

Comment: @DenizAdalar - This is not correct.  The App Store Review guidelines require that iPhone apps run correctly on an iPad - They may not be optimised for iPad and may simply present the iPhone UI, but they have to run and render correctly

Comment: If the app looks good on the iPhone 4-4S it should look good on iPad too. Use autolayout to make your app look good on all iPhone screens

Comment: @Paulw11 You're right. But if you don't forcefully break something, iPhone apps will run correctly on iPad's. I never had any issues with that.

Comment: I agree, it is probably an underlying issue that isn't obvious on the iPhone platform, but if Apple have seen issues on iPad the OP does need to address these

Answer (score 0):

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-interface) state -

> **2.10** iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

So, you don't need to optimise your app for iPad (although that is recommended and you have said you are working on it) but your app must at least work and provide a functional 'iPhone' User interface on an iPad.  It sounds like your app currently doesn't render correctly on an iPad

You should test it and address any issues before resubmitting.

Answer (score -2):

You absolutely cannot create a useful iPad app without separate storyboards for the iPad. No way.

You are confused about the resolutions. The iPhone 5S resolution is 320 x 568 *with retina*. Your layout is based on a 320 x 568 point size, the iPad is based on 768 x 1024 point size (with or without retina). Just NSLog the bounds of the screen and you see it.

Comment: If this was written 6 months ago I'd agree. But now with size classes combined with Auto Layout and adaptive UI etc... I disagree. There are even examples in the WWDC session videos of writing apps (like Mail) with a single storyboard that serves both iPad and iPhone.